# what is the alternate function mysql_list_tables() in php 5

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

below is the code i used everything works well EXCEPT for

> Deprecated: Function mysql_list_tables() is deprecated in E:\xampp\htdocs\federalcreditadvocates\admin_page\view_reports.php on line 28

it's depricated.. so what i need is simple mysql_list_tables() for php version 5 or if there is a new function for this one.. please tell me i really need it thanks :)

```
<?php 
$table_query = mysql_list_tables("odesk_carlo");
$get_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($table_query);
for ($table = 0; $table < $get_num_rows; $table++) 
{
 echo "Table name: ", mysql_tablename($result, $table), "<br />";
}
?>
```

http://www.jaywebtechnologies.co.cc <-- down for now sooner it'l be http://www.jaywebtechnologies.com

Comment: or can anyone give me an alternate way to display those table names?

Comment: Execute the query `SHOW TABLES;` via `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Anything `mysql_` is deprecated...

Comment: @Esailija No, they are _planned for deprecation_. Their use is discouraged.

Comment: Anything `mysql_` has entered the deprecation process. Which is much the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Tomayto, tomahto :P

Comment: All mysql_* should not be used. They are in a state of depreciation, instead go for PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **not** all deprecated. Only some throw deprecation warnings at this time. You should certainly use other solutions, but to say it's all currently deprecated is false.

Comment: @ceejayoz then should we keep using them until they are all 100% deprecated ? Even though I said **depreciation** not **deprecated**

Comment: so is there another way to display this table names?

Comment: @YousufMemon They shouldn't be used, but to say they're deprecated or in a state of deprecation is currently untrue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

query the information_schema DB directly:

```
select TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA
where TABLE_SCHEMA='yourdbnamehere'
```

Comment: +1 this is the exact solution since no issue of deprecated mysql_* function

Answer (score 4):

You could try the docs for the function... http://php.net/mysql_list_tables

> This function is deprecated. It is preferable to use mysql_query() to issue an SQL SHOW TABLES [FROM db_name] [LIKE 'pattern'] statement instead.

Comment: In every answer regarding ``mysql_*`` functions, one should tell op that they are no more supported and are in a state of depreciation.

Comment: please take a look of above comment

Answer (score 1):

1. mySQL functions are in the deprecation process, so if you use one while ERROR_REPORTING is turned up you'll get notices in your output. But they'll still work. You should look into moving to [mySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for current and future code.
2. Many of the "hand-holdy" functions like `mysql_list_tables()` don't exist in these newer APIs, you'll have to find the equivalent MYSQL statement. In this case you want [`SHOW TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html).

Answer (score 0):

since PHP7 `mysql_list_tables` is removed, you can use this block:

```
if (!function_exists("mysql_list_tables")){

    function mysql_list_tables($dbname, $dbconnect=null){
        $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

As a **workaround**, I created a small PHP include file, that recreates all old `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*()`-functions: [fix_mysql.inc.php](https://github.com/rubo77/php-mysql-fix)

Answer (score -1):

oh i just had found the answer just a little tweak :) thanks to sir Godwinh Lopez :) all i need was mysql_query('SHOW TABLES'); and there we go!

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    echo "Table: ", mysql_tablename($result, $i), "<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, like the documentation and other answers told you.